# I don't know how to get buttons associated correctly

Tags: javascript

Hello I am very new and I don't know all the things I need to know to do this. I need the buttons to associate with ticket sales corresponding to type and, I want it to terminate after reaching a changable number of sales. I have written the code for everything I know how to do so far so if something appears left out its probably cause I am a idiot who doesn't know what I am doing

```
<div align="center">
    <div>Hello, and welcome to the Porpoise Pond Virtual Ticket Booth. We are running a special so toddlers get in for free!</div>
    <div>This menu is here to simplify ticket sales. It will automatically stop when the ticket sales when the seats are sold out</div>
    <div>Be aware that the maxium amount of ticket that can be purchased in one transaction is 10!</div>
    <div>Please press the button with the type of ticket you wish to purchase  to start ordering your tickets now.</div>
      <button onclick="Calculate();">Toddler Ticket</button>
    <button onclick="Calculate();">Junior Ticket</button>
    <button onclick="Calculate();">Adult Ticket</button>
    <div id='msg'></div>

</head>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Program name: Ticket Booth
        // Purpose: To do a transaction
        // Author: Ephraim Vickers
        // Date last modified: Today

        // Variables
            var MAX_SEAT_COUNT = 10             //Named constant
            var amountTicket                    //Amount of tickets bought
            var grossProfit
                    //Ticket prices
            var adulTicket = 0           
            var junTicket = 0
            var todTicket = 0
            var totalSales = 0                  // adulTicket + junTicket 
                    //Seats by class
            var adulNum = 0                     // number of tickets bought
            var junNum = 0
            var todNum = 0
            var extraNum = 0                    //Ticket bought over maximum

        function parseFloat(amountTicket) {

            if (amountTicket >= MAX_SEAT_COUNT) {
                extraNum = amountTicket - MAX_SEAT_COUNT;
                document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Tickets have now sold out thank you for purchasing."  // important to stop after limit
                 //end loop and display all data here like shown below remember to line up columns
                 //Ticket sale Report  <current date>
  // SEAT CAPACITY   EXTRAS            TOTAL SOLD
  // MAX_SEAT_COUNT  extraNum          amountTicket

  //  TODDLERS    JUNIORS               ADULTS
  //  todNum      junNum                  adulNum 
  //Gross Profit for today was grossProfit

              }else if    (amountTicket > 10) {
                 document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "The maximum number of tickets that can be done in one transaction is 10"
              }else {
                   amountTicket = prompt("Valued customer, please enter the number of tickets you would like to purchase.");
            parseFloat(amountTicket);
              }
              return;
              }
    function Calculate() {
        //set zeroes for all values
        adulTicket = 0
        junTicket = 0
        todTicket = 0
        amountTicket = 0
        totalSales = 0
        adulNum = 0
        junNum = 0
        todNUm = 0
        extraNum = 0
        grossProfit = 0
       //get user input
            amountTicket = prompt("Valued customer, please enter the number of tickets you would like to purchase.");
            parseFloat(amountTicket);
        grossProfit =  (adulTicket * adultNum) + (junTicket * junNum)

    }

    </script>
```

Comment: It's good practice to add semi-colons (`;`) at the end of every line of code in JS. (even if not required)

Comment: Why is `parseFloat` being overwritten? Choose another function name. You could use a `context` argument to pass `this` to `Calculate(this)` and could get `context.value` inside Calculate or pass something to know which button it is.

Comment: I am sorry but you lost me at the last part of that. I am trying to learn but so far all I have learned so far came from people in this forum and w3schools so I don't understand what some of the things that I used do I just know other people use them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a id variable to the Calculate function like:

```
<button onclick="Calculate(0);">Toddler Ticket</button>
<button onclick="Calculate(1);">Junior Ticket</button>
<button onclick="Calculate(2);">Adult Ticket</button>
```

Then you can use this id to identify what button was pressed:

```
function Calculate(id) {
        //set zeroes for all values
        adulTicket = 0
        junTicket = 0
        todTicket = 0
        amountTicket = 0
        totalSales = 0
        adulNum = 0
        junNum = 0
        todNUm = 0
        extraNum = 0
        grossProfit = 0
        switch(id){
        case 0:
        //code for toddler
        break;
        case 1:
        //code  for junior
        break;
        case 2:
        // code for adult
        break;
        }
       //get user input
            amountTicket = prompt("Valued customer, please enter the number of tickets you would like to purchase.");
            parseFloat(amountTicket);
        grossProfit =  (adulTicket * adultNum) + (junTicket * junNum)

    }
```

I hope that works for you.

Comment: could you explain what you did? I don't understand what "case" is or how to code it

Comment: I put a diferent int in every call to Calculate() if you look my code you will see that the first button (Toddler Ticket) calls Calculate(0) on click event, second button calls Calculate(1) etc. Then in you Calculate function you can get this number and identify what button was pressed (switch) 0 for toddle, 1 for junior and 2 for  adult

Comment: Thanks you. I am sorry but can I ask you to code one of them or reference a place that shows a example of this being used? Also would you know how to make a table in javascript